# Is the sequence $\frac{e^n}{n}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the sequence $$\frac{e^n}{n}$$ convergent?

I think it is not because $\log n < n$, implying that $\frac{e^n}{n} >1$ and hence the limit does not exist. Which probably also means that the sequence is unbounded.

Am I right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your reasoning is very hard to follow.  The fact that an expression is greater than $1$ does not imply that it's limit does not exist.

Comment: I mean the expression's value when n tends to infinity is infinity which is why the limit does not exist. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Note that $e^n \ge 1+n+{1 \over 2!}n^2$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: As I say, what you have written does not make sense.  If you can demonstrate that, as $n$ goes to $\infty$, this expression becomes unbounded, that would certainly be enough.

Comment: @ParardhaSarmah: this is not what you wrote in the post, and you actually proved nothing.

Comment: If you already know that the sequence diverges to infinity, why are you asking if it diverges?

Comment: Maybe the original question was asking about $e^{-n}/n$?

Comment: I was wondering whether the limit not existing implies  an unbounded sequence? Sorry just new to this topic I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @ParardhaSarmah The sequence $\sin(n)$ has no limit, but is bounded. There exists a bounded and convergent subsequence though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Notice that $$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{e^{n+1}}{n+1}=e\cdot \dfrac{e^n}{n}\cdot \dfrac{n}{n+1}>\dfrac{e}{2}a_n>1.3a_n$$therefore $$a_{n+1}>1.3a_n>(1.3)^2a_{n-1}>\cdots>(1.3)^na_1=e\cdot(1.3)^n$$which is unbounded since $e\cdot(1.3)^n$ is unbounded.

Comment: And that implies that the sequence is unbounded is that right?

Comment: Absolutely right. I will add some more details to clarify...

Comment: That was the most satisfying answer thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it helps.....

Answer (score 6):

Following your idea to use logarithm we have that

$$\log \left(\frac{e^n}{n}\right)=\log e^n-\log n=n-\log n=n\left(1-\frac{\log n}n\right)\to \infty\cdot (1-0) \implies \frac{e^n}{n}\to \infty$$

but we need to prove that $\frac{\log n}n\to 0$.

As an alternative it suffices to show, for example by induction, that

$$e^n>n^2$$

to immediately conclude by squeeze theorem that

$$\frac{e^n}{n}\ge \frac{n^2}{n}=n\to \infty$$

---

For the proof by induction we have

- base case: $n=2 \implies e^2>2^2=4$
- induction step: assume $e^n>n^2$ then

$$e^{n+1}=e\cdot e^n\stackrel{Ind.Hyp.}>e\cdot n^2\stackrel{?}>(n+1)^2$$

and the latter is true indeed

$$e\cdot n^2\stackrel{?}>(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$$

$$(e-1)n^2-2n-1\stackrel{?}>0$$

which is true for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: @Winther Opsss sorry I fix that! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We want to check if $$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^n}{n}$$ is finite.

So,
$$\begin{align}L &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^n}{n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{d(e^n)}{dn}}{\frac{dn}{dn}}\tag{L'Hopital's rule}  \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^n =\infty\end{align} $$

So, it is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial expansion:

$e=1+x$ , where $x >0$, $n>1,$  positive integer.

$e^n = (1+x)^n = 1+nx+(n(n-1)/(2!))x^2 +....>$

$(n(n-1)/2)x^2$.

Hence

$e^n/n \gt ((n-1)/2)x^2.$

Let $K >0$, real.

Archimedean principle:

There is a $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that

$N >2K/(x^2)+1$.

For $n \ge N$:

$e^n/n \gt (n-1)x^2/2 \ge$

$(N-1)x^2/2 > K$, i.e.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^n/n = \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

By the ratio test,$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{e\,n}{n+1}>1.$$

Comment: Is the ratio test applicable for sequences? 

Comment: @ParardhaSarmah: of course.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is, obviously, divergent, but the fact You have provided cannot serve as a proof: there are many sequences $a_n,b_n$ such that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}>1$ and yet $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges, take for instance $a_n=2, b_n=1$.

You can try to prove that the sequence is unbounded, divergence will follow trivially. There are several tricks that can be used: you can, for instance, apply de l'Hospital rule.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you help with a few more ways to prove that the sequence is unbounded?

Comment: You can show that $\frac{e^n}n>\frac{2^n}n$, which is trivial since $e>2$. Thus if $\frac{2^n}n$ is unbounded, so is $\frac{e^n}n$. By Stolz-Cesaro theorem if $a_n,b_n\rightarrow \infty$ then $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$. $\frac{2^{n+1}-2^n}{(n+1)-n}=2^n$, so it's trivially unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{en}{n+1}\to e>1
$$
as $n\to \infty$. In particular there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>(e-1)>1
$$
i.e. for $n\geq N$, $a_{n+1}>a_N(e-1)^{n-N+1} \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

By Otto Stolz theorem, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^n}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^n-e^{n-1}}{n-(n-1)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{n-1}(e-1)=+\infty.$$